# pass $scope.object in $http.get() method to asp.net web api

Tags: c#, angularjs, asp.net-web-api

I'm doing my first angularsjs-asp.net web api project. I am trying to send a `$scope.user` object to asp.net web api as follows-

AngularJS controller code-

```
    $scope.user = {};
    $scope.navbarCollapsed = true;
    $scope.save = function () {
          $http.get('/api/Login', $scope.user).
             success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
                 $window.location.href = 'app/views/dashboard.html';

             }).
             error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
             alert(status);    
      });      
}
```

ASP.NET web API code:

```
public class LoginController : ApiController
{
    public HttpResponseMessage get( LoginUser user) //user is shown null
    {

    }
}
```

user is shown null in server side. Any help?

UPDATE----------------

```
public class LoginUser
{
    public String LoginName { get; set; }

    public String LoginPassword { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: What fields `$scope.user` has? What fields `LoginUser` has ?

Comment: if your trying to send a object to server best thing is to do is the `POST` method.

Comment: Fast fix (not the best solution): encode to json your $scope.user JSON.parse($scope.user); In code behind use public HttpResponseMessage get( String user) {LoginUser decodeuser = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<LoginUser>(user)}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As complex data to WebApi is normally send in the request body, you have to specify that the information is encoded in the url:

```
public HttpResponseMessage get([FromUri]LoginUser user)
{

}
```

and send the user as follows:

```
$http.get('/api/Login',
    {
        'params': $scope.user
    });
```

But as your are sending login information I would recommend to switch to another HTTP verb like `POST`

**UPDATE**

Here is an example for the `POST` verb:

```
public HttpResponseMessage post(LoginUser user)
{

}
```

```
$http.post('/api/Login', $scope.user);
```

Comment: Now it's working. Great. As you suggested, would you please post an example with POST verb? I am very new to web api world. Thanks.